# Computation and Elimination (Solution Verification)

Tags: logic, solution-verification, binary, constructive-mathematics

> Consider a set B (of binary strings)  given by the introduction rules:
>   \begin{equation} \frac{}{\epsilon :B} \quad \frac{a:B}{s_{0}(a):B} \quad \frac{a:B}{s_{1}(a):B}\end{equation}
>
> \begin{equation} \frac{}{\epsilon=\epsilon:B} \quad \frac{a=c:B}{s_{0}(a)=s_{0}(c):B} \quad \frac{a=c:B}{s_{1}(a)=s_{1}(c):B}\end{equation}
>
> Find elimination and computation rules corresponding to these introduction rules.

I have worked out a proposed solution that I would be very happy if anyone could be as so kind as to verify. Cheers!

**Proposed Solution**

Just as in natural deduction, the elimination rule can be thought of as essentially determined by the introduction rule. More specifically, the elimination rule shows how to define a function on the set in terms of the canonical elements, by introducing an elimination operator. The computation rule fixes the relation between the introduction and elimination rule. Thus, I am lead to believe that the following expressions form the **B-elimination** rules.

\begin{equation} \frac{z:B \vdash C(z) \quad \text{set} \quad \vdash c:B \quad \vdash d:C(\epsilon) \quad x:B,y:C(x) \vdash e(x,y):C(S_{1}(x))}{\vdash R(c,d,(x,y)e(x,y):C(c)} \tag{1}\end{equation}

\begin{equation} \frac{z:B \vdash C(z) \quad \text{set} \quad \vdash f:B \quad \vdash d:C(\epsilon) \quad x:B,y:C(x) \vdash e(x,y):C(S_{2}(x))}{\vdash R(f,d,(x,y)e(x,y):C(f)} \tag{2} \end{equation}

\begin{equation} \frac{z:B \vdash C(z) \text{set} \quad \vdash c=c':B \quad \vdash d=d':C(\epsilon) \quad x:B,y:C(x) \vdash e(x,y)=e'(x,y):C(S_{0}(x))}{\vdash R(c,d,(x,y)e(x,y))=R(c',d',(x,y)e'(x,y)):C(c)} \tag{3} \end{equation}

Here, that is (1), $R(c,d,(x,y)e(x,y))$ is a method which first computes $c$ to canonical form, which is either $d:C(\epsilon)$ or $e(x,y):C(S_{1}(x))$ with $x:B,y:C(x)$. I choose not to write out (4) as it is so similar.

**B-computation**

Continuing on, I have the following suggestions for the B-computational rules:

\begin{equation} \frac{z:B \vdash C(z) \quad \text{set} \quad \vdash d:C(\epsilon) \quad x:B,y:C(x) \vdash e(x,y):C(S_{0}(x))}{\vdash R(\epsilon,d,(x,y)e(x,y))=d:C(\epsilon)} \tag{1a}\end{equation}

\begin{equation} \frac{z:B \vdash C(z) \quad \text{set} \quad \vdash k:C(\epsilon) \quad x:B,y:C(x) \vdash e(x,y):C(S_{1}(x))}{\vdash R(\epsilon,k,(x,y)e(x,y))=k:C(\epsilon)}  \tag{2a}\end{equation}

\begin{equation} \frac{z:B \vdash C(z) \text{set} \quad \vdash a:B \quad \vdash d:C(\epsilon) \quad x:B,y:C(x) \vdash e(x,y):C(S_{0}(x))}{\vdash R(S(a),d,(x,y)e(x,y))=e(a,R(a,d,(x,y)e(x,y))):C(S_{0}(a))} \tag{3a} \end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

Your proposed solution has some problems: it seems you are a bit confused by $s_0$ and $s_1$. I'd like to explain in words what is wrong, but I think in this case it'll be clearer if I just write a correct elimination rule instead.

You should have only *one* elimination rule, that is the following:

$$ \frac{\vdash c : B \quad z : B \vdash C(z)\;\text{set} \quad \vdash d : C(\epsilon) \quad x: B,\, y: C(x)\vdash e(x, y) : C(s_0(x)) \quad x: B,\, y: C(x) \vdash f(x, y) : C(s_1(x))}{R(c, d, e, f) : C(c)}$$

plus of course the usual rule for equality. Then the computation rules should be:

$$ \frac{z : B \vdash C(z)\;\text{set} \quad \vdash d : C(\epsilon) \quad x: B,\, y: C(x)\vdash e(x, y) : C(s_0(x)) \quad x: B,\, y: C(x) \vdash f(x, y) : C(s_1(x))}{R(\epsilon, d, e, f) = d : C(\epsilon)}$$
$$ \frac{\vdash x : B \quad z : B \vdash C(z)\;\text{set} \quad \vdash d : C(\epsilon) \quad x: B,\, y: C(x)\vdash e(x, y) : C(s_0(x)) \quad x: B,\, y: C(x) \vdash f(x, y) : C(s_1(x))}{R(s_0(x), d, e, f) = e(x, R(x, d, e, f)) : C(s_0(x))}$$
$$ \frac{\vdash x : B \quad z : B \vdash C(z)\;\text{set} \quad \vdash d : C(\epsilon) \quad x: B,\, y: C(x)\vdash e(x, y) : C(s_0(x)) \quad x: B,\, y: C(x) \vdash f(x, y) : C(s_1(x))}{R(s_1(x), d, e, f) = f(x, R(x, d, e, f)) : C(s_1(x))}$$

Can you see the difference between your version and mine? Notice that you should have a homogeneous way to treat every term of type $B$. Since every term reduces to a canonical term, the recursive principle should know what to do when its first argument is $\epsilon$, $s_0(x)$ or $s_1(x)$.